# Nginx FastCGI Skip Cache Rules for /shop/ in Wordpress woocommerce, why aren't they working?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, cache, fastcgi

I am running a LEMP server with Wordpress and Woocommerce. My site is live at https://www.mcmo.is.

My Nginx Skip Cache rules seem to be working except for on one page: https://www.mcmo.is/shop

When adding a product to the cart, and clicking "Continue Shopping", the cache doesn't update the product number in the cart on the [shop](https://www.mcmo.is/shop/) page. All of my other pages show an updated cart number after adding something to the cart.

Here are my Nginx skip cache rules & the relative location block in my virtual host:

```
# https://www.linuxbabe.com/nginx/setup-nginx-fastcgi-cache
# Don't Skip Cache by Default
set $skip_cache 0;

# https://www.linuxbabe.com/nginx/setup-nginx-fastcgi-cache
# POST requests should always go to PHP
if ($request_method = POST) {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}

# URLs containing query strings should always go to PHP
# ADMIN Note: You might want to be sure to turn off query strings in H-code wordpress theme, and other themes
# https://www.linuxbabe.com/nginx/setup-nginx-fastcgi-cache
if ($query_string != "") {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}

# Don't cache uris containing the following segments
# https://www.linuxbabe.com/nginx/setup-nginx-fastcgi-cache
# https://easyengine.io/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/plugins/woocommerce/
# https://docs.cleavr.io/guides/woocommerce/
#if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/wp-json/|/login/|/register/|/shopping-cart.*|.*add-to-cart.*|.*empty-cart.*|/cart.*|/checkout.*|/addons.*|/my-account.*|/wishlist.*|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|^/feed/*|/tag/.*/feed/*|index.php|/.*sitemap.*\.(xml|xsl)") {
#    set $skip_cache 1;
#}
# Original Linuxbabe
if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|^/feed/*|/tag/.*/feed/*|index.php|/.*sitemap.*\.(xml|xsl)") {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}

# Woocommerce
# https://blog.khophi.co/my-ultimate-ncachewowo/
if ($request_uri ~* "/shop/|/shop.*|/shopping-cart/|/shopping-cart.*|/store.*|/cart.*|/my-account.*|/checkout.*|/addons.*|.*add-to-cart.*|.*empty-cart.*") {
    set $no_cache 1;
}

# Other
if ($request_uri ~* "/login/|/register/|/addons.*|/wishlist.*") {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}

# Pass Fastcgi to PHP
location ~ \.php$ {
    # Pass FastCGI to PHP 7.4
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    # Split Path Info
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
    # The if lets NGINX check whether the *.php does indeed exist,
    # to prevent NGINX from feeding PHP FPM non php script files (like uploaded images).
    # see https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    # FastCGI Cache
    #fastcgi_cache off;
    fastcgi_cache mcmo.is;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 12h;
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout updating invalid_header http_500 http_503;
    fastcgi_cache_min_uses 1;
    fastcgi_cache_lock on;
    # Tell Nginx to send requests to upstream PHP-FPM server, instead of trying to find files in the
    # cache. If the value of $skip_cache is 1, then the first directive tells Nginx to send request
    # to upstream PHP-FPM server, instead of trying to find files in the cache.
    # ADMIN007 Note: fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache and fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache should be
    # uncommented if using google XML sitemap plugin, or Yoast SEO Plugin, or if you want to
    # enable the skip cache rules above.
    fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
    # This directive tells Nginx not to cache the response.
    fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
}
```

Here are is the relevant FastCGI info in my `nginx.conf` file:

```
http {
    ##
    # FASTCGI CACHE
    ##

    fastcgi_cache_path /var/www/cache/fastcgi_cache/mcmo.is levels=1:2 keys_zone=mcmo.is:100m max_size=700m inactive=24h use_temp_path=off; # In Memory (ramdisk)    #
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
```

What am I doing wrong in my skip cache rules and how can I fix it so that Nginx doesn't cache the shopping cart item count on https://www.mcmo.is/shop?

Comment: How do these directives appear in your Nginx configuration: `fastcgi_cache_bypass` and `fastcgi_no_cache`? Which variables are set behind it?

Comment: Hey @Bombaci Thanks for the reply. In my original post, I have added all of the relative info from my nginx.conf file as well as my virtual hosts `location ~ \.php$ {` location block which implements fastcgi_no_cache and fastcgi_cache_bypass. This should be everything needed to help me I believe. Let me know what I can do! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Writing this on my mobile, during my vacation, cause I couldn't sleep, haha. So, my apologies for any grammar mistake.

Based on your delivered configuration, you are using both `$skip_cache` and `$no_cache` variables. Since the `fastcgi_cache_bypass` and `fastcgi_no_cache` directives both reference `$skip_cache`, all conditions that should bypass the cache need to be set to `set $skip_cache 1`.

```
[..]
# enable the skip cache rules above.
   fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
# This directive tells Nginx not to cache the response.
   fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
```

Due to this, the suspect here is `set $no_cache 1`. It looks like a small mistake due to the use of different tutorials.

Thus, my suggestion for you is to change this:

```
# Woocommerce
# https://blog.khophi.co/my-ultimate-ncachewowo/
if ($request_uri ~* "/shop/|/shop.*|/shopping-cart/|/shopping-cart.*|/store.*|/cart.*|/my-account.*|/checkout.*|/addons.*|.*add-to-cart.*|.*empty-cart.*") {
    set $no_cache 1;
}
```

Into this:

```
# Woocommerce
# https://blog.khophi.co/my-ultimate-ncachewowo/
if ($request_uri ~* "/shop/|/shop.*|/shopping-cart/|/shopping-cart.*|/store.*|/cart.*|/my-account.*|/checkout.*|/addons.*|.*add-to-cart.*|.*empty-cart.*") {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}
```

Use the following command to test your configuration before restarting Nginx:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

And after that

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

Have fun and great earnings with your shop!